# How to find observations within a certain time range of each other in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset with ID, date, days of life, and medication variables. Each ID has multiple observations indicating different administrations of a certain drug. I want to find UNIQUE meds that were administered within 365 days of each other. A sample of the data frame is as follows:

```
ID    date          dayoflife    meds
1     2003-11-24    16361        lasiks
1     2003-11-24    16361        vigab
1     2004-01-09    16407        lacos
1     2013-11-25    20015        pheno
1     2013-11-26    20016        vigab
1     2013-11-26    20016        lasiks
2     2008-06-05    24133        pheno
2     2008-04-07    24074        vigab
3     2014-11-25    8458         pheno
3     2014-12-22    8485         pheno
```

I expect the outcome to be:

```
ID    N
1     3
2     2
3     1
```

indicating that individual 1 had a max of 3 different types of medications administered within 365 days of each other. I am not sure if it is best to use days of life or the date to get to this expected outcome.Any help is appreciated

Comment: Why doesn't the expected outcome contain an additional row `1 1` for `1     2013-11-25    20015        pheno`?

Comment: you are right- it should since some individuals will have multiple medications years down the line

Answer (score 1):

An option would be to convert the 'date' to `Date` class, grouped by 'ID', get the `abs`olute `diff`erence of 'date' and the `lag` of the column, check whether it is greater than 365, create a grouping index with `cumsum`, get the number of distinct elements of 'meds' in `summarise`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   mutate(date = as.Date(date)) %>%
   group_by(ID) %>% 
   mutate(diffd = abs(as.numeric(difftime(date, lag(date, default = first(date)),
               units = 'days')))) %>%
   group_by(grp = cumsum(diffd > 365), add = TRUE) %>%
   summarise(N = n_distinct(meds)) %>%
   group_by(ID) %>%
   summarise(N = max(N))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#     ID     N
#  <int> <int>
#1     1     2
#2     2     2
#3     3     1
```

Comment: sorry I am very new to R- do you mind explaining the ```group_by(grp = cumsum(diffd > 365), add = TRUE)

Comment: @sip255 It is to create a grouping variable based on the difference of adjacent elements in 'diffd'.  `v1 <- c(1, 250, 1500, 250); diff(v1)` returns the difference between adjacent elemnt, then compare whether the `abs`olutee difference is greater than 365, returns a logical vector. Wrapping with `cumsum` , adds 1 at each TRUE element, creating some kind of bins to group

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(date),
         lag_date = abs(date - lag(date)) <= 365,
         lead_date = abs(date - lead(date)) <= 365) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(lag_date, lead_date), ~ ifelse(., ., NA)) %>%
  filter(coalesce(lag_date, lead_date)) %>%
  summarise(N = n_distinct(meds))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
     ID     N
  <int> <int>
1     1     2
2     2     2
3     3     1
```

Comment: thank you! I ran into something however that I hadn't thought about before. I just edited the example code to change one of the drugs for ID 1,  and I believe the output from the code would give 4 because there would be 4 unique drugs but in different 365 day periods. How would I change this code to get an output of 3 because I am looking for the max number of unique drugs within each 365 day period for each ID?